# AOZ2264 not starting up

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, troubleshooting, schematic

I am struggling to find a reason why the AOZ2264 won't start up. I am using a 5V regulator to power the VCC pin on the AOZ2264

Find the schematics which I am using for my PCB. Not sure if there is something else I am missing. VCC pin is powered by USB 5V.[image]

Comment: Verify 5V is on Vcc pin because it does not appear on schematic to be true

Comment: The two statements are conflicting, either you power the 5V from a regulator or USB, which one is it? Also 12V to EN is too much. Maybe the chip is damaged?

Comment: VCC is 5V from USB as I cannot use the 5V0_IN as the 5V supply. I have also tried changing the pull up resistor on enable pin to connect to 5V as well and same result. I will also try another IC just in case it is damaged.